# Must manually restart lightdm to have it appear

Tags: command-line, lightdm, mate

I recently did an Ubuntu command-line install on my work laptop, then install Mate (core) and lightdm. I have an Intel graphics driver. When I turn on my computer, it boots to a black screen. Pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 allows me to login to a terminal, where I:

```
sudo systemctl restart lightdm
```

Which then makes lightdm appear. Trying to get some Ubuntu traction at work, so any help appreciated.

Comment: When you have logged in to TTY, check with `ps -ef | grep lightdm` whether or not it is running. If it is, there's something along the boot process that keeps preventing `/etc/init/lightdm.conf` from running properly

Answer (score 0):

`systemctl enable lightdm` will enable the service on boot